# SQL join mapping table and get back columns not rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

since 2 days I'm trying to find a solution...

I have two tables:

-- components -- colums: 
**id | name | description**

-- components_ingredients -- colums: 
**component_id | ingredient_id**

=> one component can have multiple ingredients

so when I join the tables with my statement:

SELECT * FROM components c
  INNER JOIN components_ingredients ci ON c.id = ci.component_id

I get back one row for every ingredient in table ci. But I want to get back only one row with the matched ingredients as additional columns like:

**c.id | c.name | c.description | ci.ingredient1 | ci.ingredient2 | ci.ingredient3 ...**

Is this possible and when how??

Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is PIVOT.  There are multiple answers to similar questions.  Here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

You can try using MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to create a CSV list of the ingredients for each given component.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.description, ci.ingredients
FROM components c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT component_id, GROUP_CONCAT(ingredient_id) AS ingredients
    FROM components_ingredients
    GROUP BY component_id
) ci
    ON c.id = ci.component_id
```

Note that as @Gordon pointed out, you might be able to do without the subquery I used, but in general you might need it.  The reason Gordon's query works, even according to the ANSI standard, is a given `id` in the `components` table should uniquely determine the `name` and `description`.  Hence, it is OK to include those columns while using `GROUP BY`, because there is no ambiguity involved.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to put the ingredients in separate columns, because you don't now how many there are.

Much easier is to concatenate them together into a string in one column:

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ci.component_id) as component_ids
FROM components c INNER JOIN
     components_ingredients ci
     ON c.id = ci.component_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Note:  It is generally bad practice to include columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  However, it is okay in this case, because `components.id` uniquely identifies each row.  This functionality is even specified as okay in the ANSI standard -- although few databases actually implement it.